# I'm looping through my array with v-for and I would like that each item goes to a specific grid position. How do I do that?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, v-for

Well, I have this component and I want to display my data in a grid that looks like this:

[image]

I'm looping through my last 3 items of my array

```
async created(){
        const res = await axios.get("https://base-url/posts")
        const data = res.data;
        this.destaques= data.slice(-3);     
    }
```

But when I use v-for I do not see a way to put them in the positions above.

```
<div v-for="(destaque, i) in destaques" :key='i'>
    <nuxt-link :to="`/${destaque.id}`">
         <p>{{destaque.title}}</p>
    </nuxt-link>
</div>
```

I've tried this way

```
        <div class="destaques__principal">
            <nuxt-link tag="a" :to='`/${destaques[0].id}`' class="wrap-link">
            <img :src="`${destaques[0].image[0].name}`" alt="">
            <div class="white-box">
                <h1 class="white-box__title">{{destaques[0].title}}</h1>
            </div>
            </nuxt-link>
            </div>
        <div class="destaques__cima">
            <nuxt-link tag="a" :to='`/${destaques[1].id}`' class="wrap-link">
            <img :src="`${destaques[1].image[0].name}`" alt="">
            <div class="white-box">
                <h1 class="white-box__title">{{destaques[1].title}}</h1>
            </div>
            </nuxt-link>

        </div>
        <div class="destaques__baixo">
            <nuxt-link tag="a" :to='`/${destaques[2].id}`' class="wrap-link">
            <img :src="`${destaques[2].image[0].name}`" alt="">
            <div class="white-box">
                <h1 class="white-box__title">{{destaques[2].title}}</h1>
            </div>
            </nuxt-link>

        </div>
```

and first it works but when I click on the logo to get back to home page, it gives me an error. I don't get that error when I display the data like this `destaque.title`. So I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically arrange the items to specific positions on the grid. Is there anyone that could help me out, please?

Comment: Have you looked into using CSS grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS grid to achieve this. DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/kpset24g/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div v-for="(item, i) in items" class="box" :class="{'full-height-box': i == 0}">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 2;
  grid-gap: 10px; /* OPTIONAL */
}

.full-height-box {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.box { /* Custom styles of your box */ }
```

*JS (Just as demo)*

```
new Vue({
  //...
  data: {
    items: ['Block 1', 'Block 2', 'Block 3']
  }
})
```